# How to install DVD 2 and 3 of debian?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer, debian-cd

There are 3 DVDs of debian on [this page](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-dvd/) after installing first by usb stick installation how to install 2nd and 3rd DVDs?

I want to install all the packages at once so that I do not need to go back and install packages as per need by mounting DVDs again and again.

I have no Internet connection for the device too.

Comment: 2nd and 3rd DVDs are for those who have a limited (or costly) Internet connection, or no Internet at all. Is it your case?

Comment: Yes, I have no adapter for wifi in my laptop and no lan wire to connect but I can download DVD from my another laptop using torrent.

Comment: And is there a way to install all the packages available in other iso, so that we don't need to go and install again and again?

Comment: You mean you don't want to insert one of the dvds each time you install a package? Installing everything is not an option IMHO but there are solutions.

Comment: PS: edit your question and state clearly that you do need those extra-dvds

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the 2 other DVD's as package sources. Insert one DVD and as root `apt-cdrom add -d /media/your_username/mount-point`, re-insert the drive when prompted to, then with sudo `sudo apt-cdrom add -d /media/$USER` Next `apt-get update`

The same for the 2 one.

Answer (score 1):

"Initially, you will only need to download and use the first image of a set (labelled as debian-something-1 to be able to start the Debian installer and set up Debian on your computer. If there are more images available here (labelled debian-something-2, debian-something-3, etc.), they contain the extra packages that can be installed on a Debian system (as mentioned previously). **They will not be bootable and are entirely optional.** If you have a fast Internet connection, you're most likely better off installing any desired extra packages directly from the Debian mirrors on the Internet instead of by using these extra images." - http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.6.0/amd64/bt-dvd/

They are just used as offline Repositories. If you have an adequate Internet connection you do not need them.

Comment: Is there a way to install all of the packages in other 2 iso at once?

Comment: -1 OP **does** need them. Your are not answering the question.

Comment: When I answered there were no comments to suggest that the OP needed them. I did say "If...". If the OP has a DVD-Rom then he might use http://sohcahtoa.org.uk/pages/wheezy-offgrid.html and scroll down to Recognising DVD-2 and DVD-3 and installing software